# Записать данные в выбранную таблицу rails

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails

Здрвствуйте. Сейчас изучаю ruby on rails и возник вопрос. Есть две связанные таблицы project и todo связаные таким образом

project.rb

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :todos
end
```

todo.rb

```
class Todo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Есть форма new

```
<%= form_for :todo, :url => { :action => :create } do |f| %>

  <%= f.text_field :text, :placeholder => ' Enter new Todo here..' %><br>
        <%= f.select(:project_id) do %>
        <% [['Family', 1], ['Work', 2], ['Other', 3]].each do |c| -%>
        <%= content_tag(:option, c.first, value: c.last) %>
      <% end %>
<% end %><br>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

И контроллер todo

```
class TodoController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
      @todos = @project.todos
      @todo = Todo.new
  end

    def new
        @todo = Todo.new
  end

    def create
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @todo = @project.todos.create(todo_params)
  redirect_to project_path(@project)

  end



    def show
     @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
  end

   private
  def todo_params
    params.require(:todo).permit(:text, :isCompletetd, :project_id)
  end

end
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы todo добавлялось не в выбранный в стороке project

.../project/1/todo/new - все добавляется в первый project

А тот project который был выбран на станице new в пункте f.select(:project_id)

Я думаю что нужно переписать

```
@project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
```

Но каким образом, найти не могу

Comment: У вас что-то не так с роутами. `.../project/1/todo/new` предполагает, что вы создаете тудушку для первого проекта. Можно заставить работать и при таких роутах - посмотрите внимательно в логи у вас там должен быть `project_id` внутри хэша `todo`, вот по нему и надо искать

Comment: Именно, внутри кеша todo есть project_id но каким образом его вытащить я найти не могу.

Comment: `params[:todo][:project_id]` - всё просто. Подумайте ещё раз над вашими роутами всё же, очень нелогично выглядит

Answer (score 0):

`params[:todo][:project_id]` - всё просто